# JSON not passing from Node.js to .getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have the following code in my client which is executed on page load. My client pages and JS are hosted by mode my Node.js script with Express

```
    initHomePage : function(options) {
        $.getJSON('siteinfo.json',
             function(data) {
              //called when complete
              alert('process complete' + data);
             });    
    },
```

Which is calling the following Node.js

```
exports.get_site_setup = function (req, res) {
var dbc;

async.waterfall([
    // get a connection

    function (callback) {
        db.db(callback);
    }

    ,querylookup    
], completed);

function querylookup(dbclient, callback) {
    dbc = dbclient;
    dbc.query("SELECT site_id, "+
                "name, "+
                "quicklist, "+
                "image, "+
                "image2, "+
                "message, "+
                "fbflag, "+
                "facebookurl, "+
                "twflag, "+
                "twitterurl, "+
                "contactflag, "+
                "contactemail, "+
                "eventsflag, "+
                "loyaltyflag, "+
                "loyaltyclub, "+
                "loyaltymessage, "+
                "location_id, "+
                "locdescription "+
                "FROM LOCATION_LOOKUP_ACTIVE_VIEW "+
                "where site_id = 7 and location_id = 8",
            callback); 
}

function completed (err, rows, fields) {
    if (dbc) dbc.end();
    if (err) {
        callback (err);
    } else {
        console.log(rows[0]);
        res.contentType('json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(rows[0]));
    }

}
};
```

My console.log is firing and showing my expected JSON in the console when I expect the the request to be made.

However the alert box that pops up in my browser says

"process complete[object Object]"

Why is my JSON not passing from my server side to my client script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you send back is being parsed into a JavaScript object. If instead of an alert you did

```
console.dir(data);
```

it'd be clearer.

That's kind-of the *whole point* of `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: I'm only doing an alert to test that I am indeed receiving the proper JSON before I do something with it.

Comment: His point is that `data` is no longer a JSON string when you attempt to `alert()` it, it's already been parsed into a native javascript object.  So, what you're really doing is this: `alert('process complete'+data.toString())`... and when you `.toString()` an object literal, you get `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what @Pointy says, 'data' that you are trying to show in the alert should be the JSON response. Try stringify as below if you want to see it in alert :

```
alert('process complete ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: OMG..lol that completely didn't even occur to my brain...thanks Guys!

Comment: To continue on with this discussion..do I then reference to it as JSON in my client scripts just as I would normally?

Comment: @ddpishere well what your function gets is a full-blown JavaScript object.  The concept of "JSON" Is really more of a serialization scheme; once it's been parsed and turned into a JavaScript object, it's just an ordinary object.